# Limit of a complex sequence is finite - how to disprove the claim

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I've been given the following assignment:

**Prove/disprove that the limit of (Zn)^3 is a finite number if and only if the limit of Zn is a finite number when n approaches infinity.**

I've proved the claim for an infinite limit but I was told this claim is supposed to be disproven, although I assumed initially that the proof is identical, so I couldn't find a way to get it right.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If $a,b,c$ denote the three complex roots of $z^3-1$, then the sequence $(a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c\cdots)$ has no limit, but the sequence $(a^3,b^3,c^3,a^3,b^3,c^3,\cdots)$ has of course a limit, since all entries are $1$.

Comment: Thank you, sir!